# PCMU fade out effect

Tags: algorithm, audio, encoding, effects, pcm

I want to achieve PCMU fade out effect of the audio. Lets say I have two pieces of 160 bytes of audio which correspond to 20ms audio duration each and I want to insert some silence between them but I want smooth transition from the first piece to silence and then from silence to the second piece.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to convert the PCMU samples within the transition to linear values, scale them according to your transition function, then convert them back to PCMU.

There *may* be a way of doing this while remaining in the µ-Law domain, since scaling becomes addition/subtraction, but it will be fiddly to get right and probably not worth the loss of portability/simplicity unless you are really pushing the performance envelope.

Comment: this is for VOIP application so performance is important here. I could probably afford to decode to linear audio and do some calculations there without affecting the performance too much but I would prefer if there is a way to do it with the pcmu samples.  I am not aiming for really nice and quality fade out effect I just want to avoid the "clicking" which I hear from the player when I add silence at some place in the stream. What do you mean by addition/subtraction?

Comment: Basic math: you can multiply/divide a log value by adding/subtracting. In theory you can extract the log quantity form your µ-Law samples, subtract an appropriate value corresponding to the log of your envelope function, and then stuff the modified log sample bits back into the sample. Messy, though.

Comment: Thanks this seems enought to get me going!

Answer (score 0):

you can lower volume down to complete silence and then start another piece raising its volume from 0

volume modification is pretty simple. if your audio is 2 bytes samples so just take a sample as 16bit integer and treat it as a volume level. E.g. you need to lower volume from current level to 0 smoothly during 5 seconds. Take last 5 seconds of your first piece and modify it, e.g. for each 2 bytes sample calculate new volume level (according of its timestamp to provide smooth volume change effect) as a fraction of 1 and multiply by sample value.

Comment: It's PCMU though - the samples are logarithmic (µ Law).